# "it is not to be" vs "it should not be"

Tags: modal-verbs

In the following sentence:

> It contains privileged and confidential information **which is not to be** disclosed.

if I replace the bold part with "which should not be", how the meaning changes? Are these two phrases interchangeable?

Thanks

Comment: _"which **is** not to be disclosed"_ is a much stronger of a statement than the "should" version. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It contains privileged and confidential information, which is not to be disclosed.

I think we can replace "not to be" with "should not be" in this sentence,  without any significant difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

They are not interchangeable. "Should not to be" is not grammatical. If you want to use "should", just say "should not be".

Comment: Sorry, I meant "should not be". I correct my question.

Answer (score 1):

They don't necessarily mean the same thing, but in this case, they do.  The second definition of `should` ([on MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/should)) expresses "obligation, propriety, or expediency".   That is what `is not to be` means here.